# Title question: Does this read well?

Tags: phrase-request, headlinese

I have an infographic I am creating and we are struggling to design a title that uses some larger words.

The original name was "9 Easy Steps To Buying Nonprofit Fundraising Software" and now after some time on the cutting floor, it has become a tie between:

- "9 Step Guide To Buy NonProfit CRM"
- "9 Part Guide To Buy NonProfit CRM"
- "Roadmap To Buy NonProfit CRM"
- "Navigation To Buy NonProfit CRM"

So the one I am having trouble with is the last one, which I have designed as below:
[image: Title In Question]
[image: Title In Question 2]

So basically, does this read well to you? Is the grammar of it bad enough to stop you from reading on? If not, how could I change it?

Comment: "Guide to {what}", not "guide to {do}", so "Guide to buying".

Comment: @VictorBazarov Would something along the lines of "Taking Steps To Buy Nonprofit CRM" be better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for free ad copywriting.

Comment: @StoneyB Not really considering I have what I need written, I just need a way to make it grammatically correct. It would be one thing if I just came here and said "write me a title." Instead, I provided examples and asked for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Victor in the comments, it should be buying rather than buy.Of the options presented, 1 and 3 seem to say what you want, personally I prefer 1

> 9 step guide to buying non profit crm

Over

> roadmap for buying non profit crm

The second one

> 9 part guide to buying non profit crm

to a native ear (well, to mine anyway) implies that this is one of a 9 infographic series on the subject, rather than a 9 step guide in a single infographic which is what I think you want.

The fourth one I'm afraid just doesn't make sense, navigation is something you do, not an item you can hold like a guide or a map.

Comment: Actually, that is my mistake in wording, I do want to use Step, since it is 9 'panels' on 1 document. Not 9 documents. I have come to the conclusion of using "9 Step Guide **To Buying** Nonprofit CRM".

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're most welcome, it does sound like 'step' is what you mean.

Comment: Yup, everything came out great, my coworker and I were just racking out brains on how to phrase something. Just had to modify the design a little.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a suggestion: "a step-by-step guide..."

The phrase ***step-by-step*** is an established idiom; [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/step-by-step_1) defines it as:

> **step-by-step** (*adj*.) progressing gradually from one stage to the next   ⇒ *Follow our simple step-by-step instructions* ⇒ *a step-by-step guide to oil painting*

This phrase has a couple of advantages:

- (1) If you ever add or delete a step, you wouldn't have to change your artwork or literature.
- (2) The expression gives the impression that your guide will be easy to follow.

---

<sup>As a footnote, I'm limiting my answer to the suggestion of using "step-by-step guide" in your materials. Telling you the "best" way to market your materials is an off-topic marketing question, but suggesting an English idiom that could be included is an on-topic English learner's question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with "Our Company's 9 Step Guide To Buying Nonprofit CRM"

[image: New Title]